# Parse XML in SQL server for specific value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am looking for a way to retrieve specific info embedded in XML in SQL Server Database

Right now my query is :

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    XML.query('/CatalogItem/parameters/.').value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as [Info]
FROM 
    [ePO].[dbo].[UDLP_DEFINITIONS] 
WHERE 
    [Type] = '80' OR [Type] = '81' AND CatalogID = 'D1234'
```

The result is

```
Name = Mobizen 32Go

Info = <conditions><condition grouping="or"><prop-key>vid_pid</prop-key><op-key>equals</op-key><value><![CDATA[1F75||0903||]]></value></condition></conditions>
```

Can you tell me how to get output formatted like this in my example:

```
NAME                    VID            PID
---                     ---            ----
Mobizen 32 Go          1F75            0903
```

Values for VID / PID must come from ![CDATA field in `<value>`

Many thanks

Gerald

Comment: What is the original XML, please [edit]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what the original xml looks like I've just done it with your original query as a subquery, feel free to refactor it.

```sql
SELECT Name, 
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Info.value('(conditions/condition/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')), '||', '.'), 1)) VID,
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Info.value('(conditions/condition/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')), '||', '.'), 2)) PID
FROM (
  SELECT
      Name, 
      XML.query('/CatalogItem/parameters/.').value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as [Info]
  FROM 
      [ePO].[dbo].[UDLP_DEFINITIONS] 
  WHERE 
      [Type] = '80' OR [Type] = '81' AND CatalogID = 'D1234')
```

Comment: How can I run and test your sql?

Comment: The original XML for this record is : <conditions><condition grouping="or"><prop-key>vid_pid</prop-key><op-key>equals</op-key><value><![CDATA[1F75||0903||1F75 - 0903]]></value></condition></conditions>

Comment: The thing is this database is a sample of McAfee EPO, it won't be easy to reproduce for you. Unfortunately i cannot get d0little query to work, it is throwing me a syntax error after the last bracket. Another thing i wanted to test is that with a xpath tester i was able to get what I want (value:1F75|0903) with the xpath expression /conditions/condition/value/text()    Any suggestion on how to set the xpath expression on the sql statement, and get result 1F75|0903 ? Anyway thanks to people who try to help me on this :-)